# Sass import or extend?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a main.scss and bootflat.scss, I want to change some things on bootflat style. Is that correct I use @extends: 'bootflat.scss' instead of @import: 'bootflat.scss'?

It's because I don't want a very extensive main.CSS compiled file, and when I use @import, my main.CSS became a lot of lines.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only reference `main.css` in your html, `@import` is fine. If you want to have references to both `bootflat.css` and `main.css`, then you shouldn't import one to the other.

`@extends` really has a different purpose than what you're thinking here. It's mostly used *inside* selectors in your css.

For your purposes, either keep the two files separate and reference both from html, or import one and have a single reference in html.

Comment: So, as I don't want a bigger main.css the better choice would be use 2 references in the html?

Comment: @MaxFerreira That's fine, yes. But there's no real downside to having a large css file. As the developer, you should only be editing your sass files. So, deploying the css as one large file shouldn't make too much difference to you.